# Class annotations and class loader in Java 11

Tags: java, classloader, java-9, java-module, urlclassloader

I've [some JavaDoc doclet](https://github.com/Rothamsted/ondex-base/blob/202002_jdk11/core/workflow-api/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/ondex/doclet/PluginDoclet.java), just rewritten for the new Java Doclet API, which is run by the Maven plugin, which does this:

1) Loads some jars from a directory and adds them to the context class path. This is like:

```java
URL[] urls = <all .jar URLs>
URLClassLoader xClsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance ( urls, Thread.currentThread ().getContextClassLoader () );
Thread.currentThread ().setContextClassLoader ( xClsLoader );
```

2) Searches for all the instances of a root class and, for each of them, tries to pick a given annotation:

```java
String classFQNs = ...
for ( String fqn: classFQNs )
{
  Class dynCls = Thread.currentThread ().getContextClassLoader ().loadClass ( fqn );
  Status statusAnnotation = dynCls.getAnnotation ( Status.class );
  if ( statusAnnotation == null )
    // DAMN IT! IT'S ALWAYS NULL!
}
```

The problem seems to be that Status.class is both in the classpath loaded by Maven together with the plugin, AND in the additional .jar that I add to the classpath seen by the doclet. I cannot remove it from the Maven Java Javadoc's dependencies, cause that would break the code doing 2), if I don't load that same .jar in 1), the JavaDoc scan fails, because many classes in the other jars involved in 2) extend a root class in this troubling .jar.

Yes, I could rearrange the code, split the .jar, use an alternative to javadoc, etc, but all of those options would imply huge changes in a legacy project, which isn't be best quality code you can imagine.

So, what's going on? This used to work up to Java 8, I understand Java >= 9 now sees the same class coming from different jars as different classes, even different unnamed modules, so that the annotation in the loaded class isn't considered the same as the one that the doclet tries to fetch, despite `Status` is exactly the same, just loaded differently, once by Maven the other time by my code in 1). How could I overcome that? Is there another way to load those .jars? Is there a way to reconcile those same annotations?

Comment: "_I understand Java >= 9 now sees the same class coming from different jars as different classes_" – it has always been the case that two `Class` objects are equal if, and only if, they both have the same binary name and they were both loaded by the same `ClassLoader`.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, it doesn't seem the case, though, I debugged it with type casting and Class.isAssignableFrom () (yes, they might be using different class loaders). The doclet source is linked in my question, it scans the classes (which, conceptually are plugins) and spawns a descriptor XML from their annotations.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] where a `Doclet` implementation attempts to get a compiled annotation from a compiled class, including the `javadoc` arguments? Note that one solution could be to search the present annotations by name, instead of by class. Also, it may be possible to use the [Language Model API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/package-summary.html) via [`DocletEnvironment#getIncludedElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/DocletEnvironment.html#getIncludedElements()).

Comment: @Slaw, I know, that should be easier to follow, for myself too. I'll try to write something like that later, thanks again. For the moment, I've actually fixed it by fetching annotation values entirely via reflection, but it's very ugly, I'd like to do better.

Comment: Don’t use `Thread.currentThread ().getContextClassLoader()` as the parent loader of your new `URLClassLoader`. Instead, use `Status.class.getClassLoader()` as parent loader.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger, will try. Could you explain why? Status.class should belong in the same CL of current thread.

Comment: `URLClassLoader` follows the standard delegation model of trying the parent loader first. If it uses a class from one of its jar files, it's a clear sign that whatever has been specified as parent loader doesn't know a class of that name. Since anyone can call `setContextClassLoader ` on a `Thread`, it's an unreliable property. Don't use it, when you know precisely, which class loader you actually need.

Comment: Can you check your class path with JDK 8 vs. 11? It looks like you've somehow ended up with a JAR on your class path containing the Status class that was not there when you deployed with JDK 8. As @Holger says, URLClassLoader has always done parent first delegation, nothing has changed there.